# 2007 BMW E90 320i Individual

Tags: engine, bmw, part-identification, e90

[image]Hello this plastic cover that is in the green box is cracked after having a front-end collision and I need to replace it does anyone know the name of this part cheers.

Comment: When you go to the dealer just tell them it is the plastic shield behind the bonnet catch.

Comment: @SolarMike - Maybe they don't want to get it from the dealer? Usually a lot more expensive than a used part, but you still need to know what to call it if you start asking at a salvage/junk yard or on the interwebz.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 So plastic shield didn't do it for you?

Comment: @SolarMike - I cannot see the image here at work or I'd answer the question for the OP.

Comment: For future references, the website http://realoem.com is an online system to look BMW part numbers up. If you enter the last 7 digits of your VIN number it will automatically select the correct model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of the air induction system. It is called a **Suction Hood**. BMW part number 13717541738. It can be found as #15 in the diagram below.

[image]

[Source](http://www.realoem.com/bmw/enUS/showparts?id=PG51-EUR-07-2007-E90N-BMW-320i&diagId=13_1146)

Comment: I had an answer up, but yours is a lot more authoritative. Deleted answer and +1 to you.